# Accessing scope params of children directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new in AngularJS, using it for two months in a project. I've learned how to use directives and theirs scopes (false, true, obj literal), but there's some questions about it...

First of all, we have some `ng-repeats` and directives with some behaviors, I tried to present a equivalent scenario in [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/naandoaraujo/7zkts5nq/6/).

1. I didn't figure out how to access a function (`testfn` - within `ng-controller`) inside a directive child of another directive `myItemDirective`. But in `myStepDirective` it's accessible, I tried to pass it like in the first "layer" but didn't work.

   PS.1: I created a `myStepDirective` with a isolated scope for other examples, if you need, just uncomment to test. Both I got a way to access params/functions from parent (controller), but not inside a grandchild.
2. Why directive's scope params doesn't work with camel case params? I don't remember to read some hint in AngularJS docs... `typewithnocase` inside `myItemDirective` works but `typeList` not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED]
For your 1. Here is a working fiddle working with limited scope and camel to snake case conversion : https://jsfiddle.net/wu0avqau/
I spend a loooooong time not understanding why it didn't worked but you juste forgot a = in your ng click inside  your second directive

```
ng-click"testfn()"
```

For your 2. I can refer you to the documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

> ### Normalization
>
> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which  >elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their     case->sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g. ngModel). However, since HTML is   case->insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms,   typically >using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).
>
> The normalization process is as follows:
>
> Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes.
> Convert the :, -, or _-delimited name to camelCase."

basicaly your myItemDirective would be my-item-directive inside your template but still be myItemDirective inside your js.

Good luck,
Thibaud Lamarche

Comment: I've edited my answer with a solution for your issue.

Comment: Thanks @thibaudl, it was just a little normalization detail that I used to know but didn't realize (**ng-model** doh!!) hahahahha I forked your fiddle with some stuff to demystify and help other begginers: https://jsfiddle.net/naandoaraujo/ffp2jvry/